# WordPress Revolution Slider captions only via css

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add custom captions and have trouble with it. First of all, I am using a Multisite WordPress and don't want to edit the `captions.css` in the plugins-folder. So I tried:

```
.rev_slider .tp-caption .my_head{
            position: absolute; 
            color: #4C9141; 
            text-shadow: none; 
            font-weight: 700; 
            font-size: 20px; 
            line-height: 20px; 
            font-family: Arial; 
            margin: 0px; 
            border-width: 0px; 
            border-style: none; 
            white-space:nowrap; 
            text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);        
        }
```

I inserted it into the custom css by the Theme -> don't work. Then I tried it in the `style.css` -> don't work. After this I clicked the `EDIT CSS` button in the `wp-admin`. Inserted the code starting with: `.tp-caption.my_head{`. pressed the Update-button -> don't work and the file wasn't updated.

Did I a simple mistake or is everything completely wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should do changes not in internal WP revolution Slider CSS editor but in file wp-content/themes/---/css/slider.revolution.css.
This file overwrites core revolution slider CSS.

Comment: Remove or comment lines 37 and 38 in file "wp-content/themes/----/layouts/before.php"

    "  wp_register_style('revslider-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/slider.revolution.css');
      wp_enqueue_style('revslider-css');"

or simply do file slider.revolution.css empty.Then Revolution slider will be use own CSS

Comment: See if the above solution helps.

Comment: @newTag great idea. I created the slider.revolution.css and put it into my child theme (I know that I forgot to mention it). I played around to figure out how it will work. But my styles are still not appearing in the slide options. I can't edit the before.php

Comment: @newTag Is there a was to get before.php in child theme too? It will solve my problem, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Just type in the `styles.css` of the Child-Theme:

```
#sections .rev_slider .tp-caption.large_text 
    {
    font-family: @fancyFont; 
    font-size: 35px; 
    color: #4C9141; 
    text-shadow: none;
    ...
    }
```

I cannot add additional styles but i can alter some of them.

Answer (score 0):

In Revolution Slider (mine is version 1.2.8) there is a section for static css ==> and this generates a file called "static.css".

This contains styles that override all other, so you can just put your code inside it.